# Errors in the console with Stripe, ReactJS. Could not find Elements context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

So, I'm making a webapp like Udemy.

I'm stuck with errors in the console while pressing checkout on my checkoutpage. I can add and remove things to the basket and login/logout. But when I have added courses to my basket and then presses checkout, it only gives me a white page.

***Console error:***
Uncaught Error: Could not find Elements context; You need to wrap the part of your app that calls useStripe() in an  provider.

I have tried to find a solution for this but I am completely stuck. I tried changing the  tag in the CheckoutPage.tsx from ChekoutPage to Checkout, without success.

What is the solution here?

Adding my code below.

**Checkout.tsx**

```
import {
  CardCvcElement,
  CardExpiryElement,
  CardNumberElement,
  useElements,
  useStripe,
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { Card, Form, Input, notification } from "antd";
import { ChangeEvent, SyntheticEvent, useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import agent from "../actions/agents";
import { removeBasket } from "../redux/slice/basketSlice";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "../redux/store/configureStore";
import CheckoutSummary from "./CheckoutSummary";

const Checkout = () => {
  const [cardName, setCardName] = useState<string>("");

  const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setCardName(e.target.value);
  };

  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  const { basket } = useAppSelector((state) => state.basket);

  const handlePayment = async (event: SyntheticEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!stripe || !elements) return;

    try {
      const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardNumberElement);

      const paymentResult = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(
        basket?.clientSecret!,
        {
          payment_method: {
            card: cardElement!,
            billing_details: {
              name: cardName,
            },
          },
        }
      );
      if (paymentResult.paymentIntent?.status === "succeeded") {
        await agent.Users.addCourse();

        notification.success({
          message: "Your payment is successful",
        });
        dispatch(removeBasket());
        await agent.Baskets.clear();
        setTimeout(() => {
          history.push("/profile");
        }, 1000);
      } else {
        notification.error({
          message: paymentResult.error?.message!,
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="checkout">
      <div className="checkout__form">
        <h1>Checkout Page</h1>
        <Card title="Fill your Card details here">
          <Form form={form} layout="vertical">
            <Form.Item
              name="cardName"
              rules={[
                { required: true, message: "Card Name is required", min: 5 },
              ]}
              label="Name on Card"
            >
              <Input
                name="cardName"
                placeholder="Mention the name on your card"
                value={cardName}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item label="Card Number">
              <div className="stripe-input">
                <CardNumberElement />
              </div>
            </Form.Item>
            <div className="inline">
              <Form.Item label="Expiry Date">
                <div className="stripe-input">
                  <CardExpiryElement />
                </div>
              </Form.Item>
              <Form.Item label="CVV">
                <div className="stripe-input">
                  <CardCvcElement />
                </div>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          </Form>
        </Card>
      </div>
      <div className="checkout__summary">
        <CheckoutSummary handleSubmit={handlePayment} stripe={stripe} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Checkout;
```

**CheckoutPage.tsx**

```
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import agent from '../actions/agents';
import Checkout from '../components/Checkout';
import { setBasket } from '../redux/slice/basketSlice';
import { useAppDispatch } from '../redux/store/configureStore';

const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_51Lv9phKvRfW7UNmx3CSrYjK0IJGlPkQH7TtngJCCe2eawIk7AUw2WMwbt7lnawxsnqrELEdbdbxPhVEI6sCzY2dR00HOJ0aYYQ');

export default function CheckoutWrapper() {
  
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    agent.Payments.paymentIntent()
      .then((basket) => dispatch(setBasket(basket)))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
      <Checkout />
    </Elements>
  );
}
```

**App.tsx** (provided by OP in an answer below)

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './sass/main.scss';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import HomePage from './pages/Homepage';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import DetailPage from './pages/DetailPage';
import Categories from './components/Categories';
import CategoryPage from './pages/CategoryPage';
import DescriptionPage from './pages/DescriptionPage';
import BasketPage from './pages/BasketPage';
import { useAppDispatch } from './redux/store/configureStore';
import { fetchBasketAsync } from './redux/slice/basketSlice';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute';
import CheckoutPage from './components/Checkout';
import { fetchCurrentUser } from './redux/slice/userSlice';
import Loading from './components/Loading';

function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const appInit = useCallback(async () => {
    try {

      await dispatch(fetchCurrentUser());
      await dispatch(fetchBasketAsync());
      
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error);
    }

  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    appInit().then(() => setLoading(false));
  }, [appInit]);

  if (loading) return <Loading />

  return (
    <>
      <Navigation />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Categories} />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route exact path="/course/:id" component={DescriptionPage} />
        <Route exact path="/basket" component={BasketPage} />
        <Route exact path="/category/:id" component={CategoryPage} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/detail" component={DetailPage} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/profile" component={Dashboard} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/checkout" component={CheckoutPage} />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thanks :)

Comment: None of this is C# and it doesn't even sound like the errors you're getting are related to C# or .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks very similar to the [minimal hooks-based example](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js#using-hooks) so I would expect it to work.

Can you share the code that loads `CheckoutPage`? I suspect you might be accidentally loading `<Checkout />` directly, bypassing the necessary `Elements` provider.

**Edit based on update:**

Yes, based on the App.tsx file you shared, you're importing the Checkout *component* instead of the *page*.

`import CheckoutPage from './components/Checkout';`

This should probably instead be importing `./pages/CheckoutPage`.

Comment: Yes, posted the App.tsx file.

Comment: Thanks @Nolan H, just removed the comment down below since it's not an answer. I will try that right away!

Comment: Thanks! Solved the problem.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it :)